# can I pull in just the first name of an approver in an approval process into an email template?

Tags: email-template, approval-process, merge-field

I have an email template used in an approval process for the first approver/entry.
the users want it to just be addressed to the first name, not the full name of the approver but I don't see any way to do that.
There aren't many choices for pulling in the approvers user data:

[image]

Wondering if anyone has any ideas if this can be done somehow?

Comment: You might want to try using the {!User.FirstName} {!User.LastName} since the one who approves the record will be the one triggering the email alert for the approval process. [Related KI](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000001q7RvQAI)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating formula field to pull just the first name and hid it from the page layouts.